# Change the double arrow icon in connection list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

I have the below code but I couldn't get it to work

```
<style type="text/css">
IMG[src*='/_layouts/images/rbsel.gif'] 
{
BACKGROUND-IMAGE: url('https://keoic.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteOffices/SiteAssets/radio-button-selected.gif'); /* This is the url for the image to replace the selected arrow*/
WIDTH: 20px; /*this must equal the width of your new image*/
HEIGHT: 0px; 
PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px; 
PADDING-LEFT: 0px; 
PADDING-RIGHT: 0px; 
PADDING-TOP: 20px /*This must equal the height of your new image it will pad the double arrow out of view*/
}
IMG[src*='/_layouts/images/rbunsel.gif'] {
BACKGROUND-IMAGE: url('https://keoic.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteOffices/SiteAssets/radio-button-unselected.gif'); /* This is the url for the image to replace the unselected arrow*/ 
WIDTH: 20px; /*this must equal the width of your new image*/
HEIGHT: 0px;
PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px; 
PADDING-LEFT: 0px;  
PADDING-RIGHT: 0px;  
PADDING-TOP: 20px /*This must equal the height of your new image it will pad the double arrow out of view*/
}
</style>
```

[Please see here](https://brenthafnersblog.wordpress.com/2012/09/14/changing-the-double-arrow-image-used-by-sharepoints-webpart-connections/)

Here is what I did: I created a text file copy/past the above code, uploaded it to site assets, added a content editor webpart copy/paste the link to the text file from the address bar.

How do I browse through the CSS or html I tried it with firebug and dev tools but cant find `rbsel.gif` or any images or text which is shown in the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url of the images has changed to be in /_layouts/**15**/images/

So your css should be something like:

```
<style>
IMG[src*='/_layouts/15/images/rbsel.gif'] {
    BACKGROUND-IMAGE: url('https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/windows8_icons_iconpharm/26/checked_checkbox.png');
    WIDTH: 26px;
    HEIGHT: 0px;
    PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px;
    PADDING-LEFT: 0px;
    PADDING-RIGHT: 0px;
    PADDING-TOP: 26px
}
IMG[src*='/_layouts/15/images/rbunsel.gif'] {
    BACKGROUND-IMAGE: url('https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/windows8_icons_iconpharm/26/unchecked_checkbox.png');
    WIDTH: 26px;
    HEIGHT: 0px;
    PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px;
    PADDING-LEFT: 0px;
    PADDING-RIGHT: 0px;
    PADDING-TOP: 26px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested I decided to re-use check boxes found in the spcommon.png. The ones in particular came from the task list check boxes.

```
<style>
    /* Checked image */
    IMG[src*='/_layouts/15/images/rbsel.gif'] {
        background: url('/_layouts/15/images/spcommon.png?rev=23') no-repeat -254px -66px;
        width: 16px;
        height: 0px;
        PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px;
        PADDING-LEFT: 0px;
        PADDING-RIGHT: 0px;
        PADDING-TOP: 16px;
    }
    /* UnChecked image */
    IMG[src*='/_layouts/15/images/rbunsel.gif'] {
        background: url('/_layouts/15/images/spcommon.png?rev=23') no-repeat -89px -178px;
        width: 16px;
        height: 0px;
        PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px;
        PADDING-LEFT: 0px;
        PADDING-RIGHT: 0px;
        PADDING-TOP: 16px;
    }
    </style>
```